# what does "spring-kafka without springboot" mean

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm totally new to Kafka and terribly confused by this:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#with-java-configuration-no-spring-boot

I don't understand what that even means.  What does "no spring boot mean" because that example sure as hell uses spring boot.  I'm so confused....

EDIT

if I'm using SpringBoot and spring-kafka, should I have to manually create `@Bean ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` as shown [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#with-java-configuration-no-spring-boot).  Most of the examples in the docs for setting up filtering / config / etc seem to use the "manual" configuration using `@Bean`.  Is that "normal"?  The docs are very confusing to me...especially this warning:

> Spring for Apache Kafka is designed to be used in a Spring Application Context. For example, if you create the listener container yourself outside of a Spring context, not all functions will work unless you satisfy all of the …​Aware interfaces that the container implements.

Comment: why is this warning confusing for you? It clearly states let `spring application context` be the one that handles the listener container otherwise some functionalities would not work as expected. Spring provides integration with kafka, but it needs to provide some boilerplate code for that to happen. In order to do that it needs to be able to handle the classes via application context and provide this boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2):

It's referring to the [autowired configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka), as compared to putting each property in the config via HashMap/Properties in-code.

Also, it does not use `@SpringBootApplication` or `SpringApplication.run`, it just calls a regular main method using a hard-coded `Config` class.

Comment: Exactly; Spring Framework predates Spring Boot by a decade or so; some people still use Spring without Boot (generally not new users, however). Just compare that example with the 2 examples above it to see how much infrastructure Boot automatically configures for you from properties. Without Boot, you have to declare all the infrastructure beans yourself.

Comment: so lets say I want to use this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#delegating-serialization and I'm a spring boot application.  How do I set "DelegatingDeserializer.VALUE_SERIALIZATION_SELECTOR_CONFIG" as a property in application.yml?  Also, can you speak to the warning here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#with-java-configuration-no-spring-boot.  Is that suggesting I **not** manually configure things??  The docs seem at odds if that's the case

Comment: `How do I set "DelegatingDeserializer.VALUE_SERIALIZATION_SELECTOR_CONFIG" as a property in application.yml` If a basic configuration is not provided into https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html you can always add your own bean configurations and override the default ones set up automatically from spring boot like documented on what you could do in case of not spring boot app. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#with-java-configuration-no-spring-boot

Comment: @Jason in that case you should register your own `bean` of `ProducerFactory` by providing your own configuration properties as you want

Comment: @Jason you can check my answer for more elaboration

Comment: @Jason `spring.kafka.consumer.properties` are passed into the configure method of the deserializer, so you'll need to find the string behind that constant. Then you can use in the Spring properties

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot contains the functionality of [AutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html)

What this means is that spring boot when discovers some specific `jar` dependencies it knows, in the project, it automatically configures them to work on a basic level. This does not exist in simple Spring project where even if you add the dependency you have to also provide the configuration as to how it should work in your application.

This is also happening here with dependencies of Kafka. Therefore the documentation explains what more you have to configure if you don't have `spring-boot` with `auto-configuration` to make `kafka` work in a spring project.

Another question asked in comment is what happens in case you want some complex custom configuration instead of the automatic configuration provided while you are in a `spring-boot` app.

As [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html)

> Auto-configuration tries to be as intelligent as possible and will
> back-away as you define more of your own configuration. You can always
> manually exclude() any configuration that you never want to apply (use
> excludeName() if you don't have access to them). You can also exclude
> them via the spring.autoconfigure.exclude property.

So if you want to have some complex configuration which is not automatically provided by `spring-boot` through some other mechanism  like a `spring-boot` specific application property, then you can make your own configuration with your custom `bean` and then either automatic configuration from `spring-boot` for that class will back of as spring does several intelligent checks during application context set up or you will have to exclude the class from auto configuration manually.

In that case you could probably take as an example reference of how to register manually your complex configurations in spring boot what is documented on how to be done in non spring boot app. [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#with-java-configuration-no-spring-boot)